# Databinding bindingadapter with multiple parameters not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-binding-adapter

I´m trying to use databinding for loading an image with Glide, Imageview and Bindingadapter with multiple parameters:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["url", "defaultImage", "placeholder", "circleCrop"], requireAll = false)
fun ImageView.setImageUrl(url: String, defaultResId: Int? = null, placeHolderResId: Int? = null, circleCrop: Boolean = false) {
    val glideRequest = if (defaultResId != null) GlideApp.with(context).loadOrDefault(url, defaultResId)
    else GlideApp.with(context).load(url)
    if (placeHolderResId != null) glideRequest.placeholder(placeHolderResId)
    if (circleCrop) glideRequest.circleCrop()
    glideRequest.into(this)
}

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfile"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/size_avatar_search_result"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:circleCrop="@{true}"
        app:defaultImage="@{@drawable/default_avatar}"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:placeholder="@{@drawable/default_avatar}"
        app:url="@{item.profilePhotoUrl}"
        tools:src="@drawable/default_avatar" />
```

The bindingadapter method is a top level function. When compiling I get the databinding-kapt error 'Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:circleCrop' with parameter type boolean on android.widget.ImageView', as if my bindingadapter is not recognized. 
Not sure what I´m doing wrong

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even though, that compiler says the problem is with `app:circleCrop`, the actual problem is with the `defaultResId` and `placeholderResId`.

When using drawables in xml `@{@drawable/default_avatar}`, it is always compiled into `Drawable`.

Therefore your binding adapter has to have signature:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = ["url", "defaultImage", "placeholder", "circleCrop"], requireAll = false)
fun ImageView.setImageUrl(url: String, default: Drawable? = null, placeholder: Drawable? = null, circleCrop: Boolean = false) {
  // code
}
```

You can see the result when you look at the generated code (e.g for layout `fragment_something.xml` it usually is `FragmentSomethingBinding`) and there you would see that the drawable resource uses `getDrawableFromResource()` function.

Comment: I have same problem, did you fix it?

Comment: ```@BindingAdapter(value = {"anchorId", "isPremiumUser"})
    public static void setAnchorId(View view, @NonNull int anchorId, @NonNull boolean isPremiumUser) {....}```

This seems to not work for me.

Comment: You need to describe more, what's the issue. For example, first issue I think may be problem is, that `requireAll=false` is missing and you don't use both properties (but that's just guess). Show the xml please :)

Comment: @ekouChiq
You need to use square brackets for arrays in Kotlin.
So it's like this:
`@BindingAdapter(value = ["anchorId", "isPremiumUser"]) public static void setAnchorId(View view, @NonNull int anchorId, @NonNull boolean isPremiumUser) {....}`

@mlyko
You probably need to edit your answer as well.